# Django Filter and Sum Value depends on different model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

_Hi, guys! I'm trying to sum times for users for each Month(Mission), like this:

```
times = goal.time_set.filter(day__year=today.year, day__month=today.month)
```

Then I will sum:

```
for time in times:
    total_min[member_number] = total_min[member_number] + time.value
```

But it calculates for current Month(Mission).
I want to calculate time depends on object model Mission. Model Mission:

```
class Mission(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
description = models.TextField(default='')
add_info = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
theme = models.ImageField(upload_to='themes/', default='themes/default.png')
date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
date_finished = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Like this I think:

```
times = goal.time_set.filter(day__year=mission.date_created.year, day__month=mission.month_created.month)
```

How can I achieve it?

upd. Goal model:

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('in progress', 'in progress'),
        ('completed', 'completed'),
        ('failed', 'failed')
    )
    id_ninja = models.ForeignKey(Ninja, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    id_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS, default='in progress')
```

Comment: Can you show your `goal` model? What is `total_min` supposed to do? This will likely be solved by Django's ORM aggregation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: I added model Goal. Total_min keeps all time for the each month for each user.
But now it keeps all time for each user only for current month. I need connect it with all monthes for memory (history).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in my way.

```
mission_year = mission.date_created.strftime('%Y')
mission_month = mission.date_created.strftime('%m')
times = goal.time_set.filter(day__year__gte=mission_year, day__month__gte=mission_month)
```